# Salads that are made of tomatoes, onion, chilli, coriander, salt and lemon

Tags: salad

Recently I've been making salads that are made of tomatoes, onion, chilli, coriander, salt and lemon. Then, I eat them with bread. I have no idea where this recipe is coming from. Do you have any suggestion on making recipes with these ingredients?

How can I improve this recipe, or make variations?

Comment: Are you asking for how to improve your salad? Or are you asking what else you could do with those ingredients. We don't recipe requests around here (there are much better tools/resources to do that), but if you give us an idea of what you'd like to do, we can help you out. As it stands, your question risks closure.

Comment: As talon8 says, this looks like a recipe request, which is better handled by other sites.  HOWEVER, I think what you're really asking is "does this combination of ingredients have a name?" or "how can I improve/expand on this salad?"  Either (or both!) of those would be perfectly fine questions.... and not likely to get closed.  Could you please edit the question to one of these tracks (so it won't get closed)?

Comment: Add bread and you've got some sort of panzanella

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, you're making a *[pico de gallo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_de_gallo)* salad?

Throw some fresh garlic and fresh lime juice in there.  It's delicious and will [prevent salmonella poisoning](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20202327), which is surprisingly common with uncooked salsas.

Comment: He's already got lemon juice - does lime do something special in regards to salmonella or it just *more* acid?  Just hadn't heard that before.

Comment: @rfusca: I suspect it's more than just acidity, based on [this reference](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Formulate+salsa+to+prevent+Salmonella+growth.-a0210059637).  They note that the salsa must contain both fresh garlic AND fresh lime juice.  But honestly, they taste so good in pico de gallo that it's hard to argue with.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend beginning by looking at similar recipes for salads; tabbouleh comes to mind right off the bat, as well as Israeli salad. Look into the making of these, their ingredients, and their application.

In some cases, they might be enjoyed straight, on pita, or with another particularly complementary side. No matter what yours tastes like, pairing your salad with a better transport (than the bread), or a side would be my next step.

Next, try to polish what you're making and why. Try substituting the coriander for cumin, or fennel, or whatever to see what happens. Treat your current recipe like an hypothesis. Experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Tomato is what gives your salad somewhat of a sweet touch.  Try replacing tomatoe for another sweet/sour fruit (mango is ideal for example).

Comment: Mango and Coriander are awesome together.

Answer (score 0):

Add the onion, coriander and chili's to a skillet of ground beef (or ground turkey) and serve it over tortilla chips and lettuce and you get a Nacho Salad. (or just plain nachos)

Answer (score 0):

Try tossing the salad with cooled Cous-Cous or Quinoa.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of salad is also known as a Kachumber in indian cuisine.